# Android custom dialog instantiate

Tags: android, dialog, fragment

I am trying to learn `Dialogs`

From the tutorial on androids official documentation I have created my own custom dialog:

```
public class LoginDialog extends DialogFragment {

  @Override
  public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    // Get the layout inflater
    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();

    // Inflate and set the layout for the dialog
    // Pass null as the parent view because its going in the dialog layout
    builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.login, null))
           // Add action buttons
           .setPositiveButton(R.string.signin, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
              @Override
              public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                // sign in the user ...
              }
            })
            .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                 LoginDialog.this.getDialog().cancel();
               }
            });
    return builder.create();
  }
}
```

Now I wish to call it from my activity.

So I have done the following: `(from my Login activity)`

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
android.app.Fragment prev = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("dialog");
DialogFragment fragment = new LoginDialog(prev);
```

however I get the following error:

```
prev cannot be applied to android.app.fragment
```

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong or where I should go from here.

Comment: do just this DialogFragment fragment = new LoginDialog(); and for show fragemnt.show();

Comment: @Hardik when i do this it gives me an error saying its missing a fragment

Comment: see here is a complete example ==> http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As getting:

> prev cannot be applied to android.app.fragment

because LoginDialog class not contain any constructor which take Fragment as parameter and return  LoginDialog instance .If you are using Android [DialogFragment Example](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html) you forget to `newInstance` method which return the instance of LoginDialog DialogFragment. you should do in same way or try as:

```
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
LoginDialog fragment = new LoginDialog();
fragment.show(fm, "dialog");
```

Comment: this gives me the following error at fragment.show(fm, "dialog");

cannot resolve method show(android.app.FragmentManger, java.lang.string)

Comment: @MarcRasmussen : see here [http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html](DialogFragment) both method available in DialogFragment try to do in same way